# Change names of csv files in a folder

Tags: python, xlrd

There are 100s of CSV files in a folder which I want to rename. There is an excel sheet which contains name of files from a folder to be renamed.

**Example:**
Lets consider one CSV file called `TestData_30April.csv`, which is in a folder. I want it to be renamed to `0.25-TestData_30April.csv`. The excel sheet in Column X contains the name to be renamed `(0.25-TestData_30April.csv)`.
Likewise the excel sheet contains names of all files in the folder to be renamed.

Here is the code:

```
import os

import xlrd

#Excel Sheet containing name of files to be renamed in that folder

path="C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Test_Data\\Test_Summary.xlsx"

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path) 

sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

#In excel sheet column X or col_values(23) contains the file name to be renamed

print(sheet.col_values(23))  

#Below line contains all the csv sheets

os.rename('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\AllData',sheet.col_values(23))
```

I want the files in the folder to be renamed to the name in the excel sheet. How do I map data from an excel sheet to that folder so that the renaming takes place?

Comment: Loop through all the rows in the sheet. Get the column values for the old and new names. Use `os.path.join()` to combine these with the folder path, and call `os.rename()`.

Comment: Column 23 has the new name. Where is the original name?

Comment: Original name is in the folders. The excel sheet (column X or column 23)contains only the files to be renamed.

Comment: But how do you know which original name in the folder goes with which new name in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Files name are randomly in the folder also the files names to be renamed in excel sheet are also random.Lets us consider one csv file "TestData_30April.csv" is a csv file in a folder. I want it to be renamed to "0.25-TestData_30April.csv". The excel sheet in Column X contains the name to be renamed(0.25-TestData_30April.csv).

Comment: So any file can be renamed to any name in the sheet, there's no correspondence between them?

Comment: If the folder contains `TestData_30April.csv` and `TestData_31March.csv`, and the sheet contains `0.25-TestData_31January.csv` and `0.50-TestData_28February.csv`, that's how it should rename them?

Comment: Eg:TestData_30April.csv" has to be renamed to "0.25-TestData_30April.csv". Is there a way in Python in which script reads file name from folder and rename to  "0.25-TestData_30April.csv".

Comment: If the folder contains TestData_30April.csv and TestData_31March.csv, and the sheet contains 0.25-TestData_30April.csv and 0.50-TestData_31March.csv. The names of files in that folder has to renamed what is there in the excel sheet.

Comment: I am just adding numbers like 0.25,0.50 to the orginal file name in the folder.

Comment: So you need to find the cell in the spreadsheet that contains the original name with a number before it?

Comment: Always excel sheet (Column-X) contains the name to be renamed. Eg:TestData_30April.csv is name in the folder and the excel sheet(Column-X) consists of "0.24-TestData_30April"  as a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over all the values in the column. Remove the number prefix from the name to get the original name, then do the rename.

```
dir = r'C:\Users\Desktop\AllData'
new_names = sheet.col_values(23)
for new_name in sheet.col_values(23):
    if '-' in new_name:
        old_name = new_name.split("-")[1]
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir, old_name)):
            os.rename(os.path.join(dir, old_name), os.path.join(dir, new_name))
```

Comment: Sir I am getting error.          old_name = new_name.split("-")[1]                                            " IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: That will happen if any of the cells don't have `-` in them. Are there names in the spreadsheet that don't fit the pattern?

Comment: Also, you probably need to skip the header row.

Comment: I added a check for `-` in the name.

Comment: All cells in excel sheet fit the pattern.Eg(0.25-TestData_31January,0.920-TestData_30January...etc)

Comment: If they all fit the pattern then you wouldn't get that error. There isn't a title row?

Comment: No title Row is not there

Comment: Maybe there are empty cells. As I said, the only reason for that error is if there's a cell with no `-` in it.

Comment: Only first row is empty in Column-X. While all row contains the file in the following order (0.25-TestData_31January,0.920-TestData_30January,0.330-TestData_20January...etc)

Comment: An empty row doesn't fit the pattern. Don't say they all fit the pattern. Did adding the `if '-' in new_name` test fix it?

Comment: The updated code is working with no error but the all the csv files in that folder have not been renamed.

Comment: I'm not sure why. I can't test my code, I don't have access to your files. It's time for you to do some debugging. Add print statements.